# Chemical analysis of Niddah Ma'ros

Tags: halacha, science, niddah

Is a rabbi allowed/endorsed/obligated to conduct a laboratory chemical analysis of Niddah Ma'ros before he Paskens?

Are there precedents? Are there rabbis who perform it on a regular basis?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Niddah.9.6

Comment: What would the chemical analysis achieve other than show it is blood? Maros are the different shades i.e. it is a visual thing?

Comment: @Dov it excludes potential tliyot

Comment: How could a Rabbi be obligated? What would obligate him?

Comment: If you have a mareh that is red but you suspect that’s it’s not blood, it would then be relevant to discuss using a chemical test to check if it’s blood or not. My rebbi, Rav Mordechai Willig, has used these before, and according to him he has been surprised in both directions- that it was blood or was not.

Comment: @robev he's obligated to give the most accurate answer he can

Comment: @DoubleAA we not machzik issur, we are not obligated to look for traifos except a lung, also the rama even says better not to look ויותר היה טוב שלא לבדוק כלל ולסמוך ארובא מלבדוק ולהקל במקום דאיכא ריעותא: (i understand that a little different and that in this case we relly on her hazaka)

Comment: @hazoriz here you have a red stain already. How can you apply a tliya (maybe it's lipstick not blood) when you can just check if it's lipstick directly

Comment: @DoubleAA because there was no hargasha,

Comment: @hazoriz if there is hargasha and it's safek lipstick we say safek deoraita. If no hargasha and it's safek lipstick we can say safek lekula. But it's not safek lipstick at all when chemical testing can easily distinguish blood and lipstick

Comment: @DoubleAA what would you say if it is less then a gris? (Not even dirabonon)

Comment: @hazoriz i guess depends if we view the tliya on a maacholet as a lo plug or a regular tliya